# My php program is inserting 0 instead of a string in one of the fields

Tags: php, mysqli

Im making an Api in PHP to make a crud in android studio, and I need to insert or update 4 fields in the database, but one of them is always inserting 0 instead of the string I pass (One of the fields is varchar, and the other 3 are texts, and just one of the texts is inserting 0)

Code in php:

```php
function createComponente($nome, $descricao, $riscos, $descarte){
    $stmt = $this->con->prepare("INSERT INTO componente (nome, descricao, riscos, descarte) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)");
    $stmt->bind_param("ssis", $nome, $descricao, $riscos, $descarte);
    if($stmt->execute())
       return true; 
    return false;
}
```

Code in the Api that calls the function:

```
$result = $db->createComponente(
                    $_POST['nome'],
                    $_POST['descricao'],
                    $_POST['riscos'],
                    $_POST['descarte']
                );
```

The program returns everything right, and inserts right, but the third field(riscos) always comes with a 0 instead of the string I pass.

(nome is varchar and the rest is text)

Comment: Could we get a dump of the raw $_POST array please.

Comment: `i` is integer `$stmt->bind_param("ssis", $nome, $descricao, $riscos, $descarte);`

Comment: OMG it was that, I should have put 'ssss', that was the problem, thank you!, please put it in an answer for me to choose it as right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you were binding one value as an integer, when you actually wanted a string, so php had cast it to 0

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssis", $nome, $descricao, $riscos, $descarte);
```

needs to be

```
$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $nome, $descricao, $riscos, $descarte);
```